# Insert data into mysql table from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert data from table1 into table2 and my own data into table2 in one(the same) query, but it is not working.
This is my query

```
$query='insert into table2(id,name) values("001",select first_name from table1 where table1.id="001")';
```

Please somebody should show me where I am going wrong with my query,I will be very much pleased.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into table2 (id, name) 
select '001', first_name 
from table1 
where id = '001'
```

or you could just use the `id` since it is `001`

```
insert into table2 (id, name) 
select id, first_name 
from table1 
where id = '001'
```

Comment: please I don't want to select the 001 from table1

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2(id,name) 
select "001",first_name from table1 where table1.id="001"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2 (id, name)
    select id, first_name from table1 where table1.id = '001';
```

^ why hardcode `select '001'`?